# Textbook for dynamic commodity market modelling in continuous time

Tags: commodities, textbooks, dynamic

I am seeking textbook recommendations for dynamic commodity market modelling in economics (including or excluding finance). It should focus on continuous models rather than discrete ones, thus based on differential equations (including delay differential equations) with or without stochastic features. The textbook should ideally be quite recent, exhaustively discuss most of the techniques and models used in the field and touch upon mineral commodities.

Comment: I really doubt that there is such a textbook. Your best bet is to search for such papers on google.